# Hibernate-search cannot find field in mapped component

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, components, hibernate-search

I have a User class that contains an Address. I have mapped the Address as a component. The Address variable in User is defined as @IndexEmbedded and the Address class itself as @Embeddable. The user table in the database contains columns for the fields from Address too. 
I can save the user and confirmed it does save the address fields.
I can search with a Hibernate Search Query in the user fields, this delivers expected results. However, searching for a field in Address gives the following error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Unable to find field address.place in com.prism.model.user.impl.UserImpl
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at com.prism.dao.hibernate.UserDAOTest.testSearchUser(UserDAOTest.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I am using the following versions :

- hibernate-4.3.5
- hibernate-search-4.5.1
- spring-4.0.5

Not sure if this is useful info, but the database is MySql 5.6

The User class (omitted gettes and setters) :

```
    package com.prism.model.user.impl;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.DocumentId;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Indexed;
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.IndexedEmbedded;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import com.prism.dao.audit.Auditable;
import com.prism.model.Address;
import com.prism.model.impl.AddressImpl;
import com.prism.model.impl.AuditableObject;
import com.prism.model.user.Role;
import com.prism.model.user.User;

/**
 * @see com.prism.model.user.User
 * 
 * <a href="UserImpl.java.html"><i>View Source</i></a>
 */
@Indexed
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserImpl extends AuditableObject implements User, UserDetails, Auditable, Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -34654639867985476L;
    @DocumentId
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Field
    private String username;
    @Field
    private String lastname;
    @Field
    private String middlenames;
    @Field
    private String firstname;
    @Field
    private String fullname;
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @Embedded
    private Address address = new AddressImpl();

    // Account properties
    /**
     * The hashed password
     */
    private String password;
    private int passwordtries;
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    @Column(name = "password_last_changed")
    private DateTime passwordLastChanged;
    private boolean enabled;
    @Column(name = "expired")
    private boolean accountExpired;
    @Column(name = "locked")
    private boolean accountLocked;
    @Column(name = "credentials_expired")
    private boolean credentialsExpired;
    private int status;
    @Transient
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    UserImpl() {
        super();
    }

    <omitted gettes and setters>

}
```

The Address class (getters and setters omitted) :

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.prism.model.impl;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.search.annotations.Field;

import com.prism.model.Address;
import com.prism.model.Zipcode;

/**
 * @see com.prism.model.Address
 */
@Embeddable
public class AddressImpl implements Address {

    @Field
    private String building;
    private String country;
    private String housenumber;
    @Column(name = "housenumber_addon")
    private String housenumberAddon;
    @Field
    private String place;
    @Column(name = "post_address")
    private String postAddressLine;
    @Field
    private String zipcode;
    @Column(name = "pre_address")
    private String preAddressLine;
    @Field
    private String room;
    @Field
    private String street;

    <getters and setters>

}
```

The spring application context file used for testing :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.prism" />
        <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="auditInterceptor"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.validation.mode">none</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">/data/prism/hibernate/indexes</prop>
            <prop key="jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes">true</prop>
            <prop key="jadira.usertype.databaseZone">jvm</prop>
            <prop key="jadira.usertype.javaZone">jvm</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="auditInterceptor" class="com.prism.dao.audit.AuditInterceptor">
    </bean>

     <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- 
            DAO's 
    -->
    <bean id="dao" class="com.prism.dao.hibernate.BaseDAOHibernate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDAO" class="com.prism.dao.hibernate.UserDAOHibernate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction on how to solve this is welcome. I found a reference to a problem like this [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1442), but from what I read there the versions I use should have that bug fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@IndexedEmbedded is probably evaluated on the compile type Address, which has no place attribute. AddressImpl has, but hibernate search probably does not look at the runtime types.

In generall I would not use interfaces on entity model classes.

With luke you can also have a look at the index and see which fields are available.

Michal

Comment: Thanks Michal, that was indeed the cause. Using AddressImpl instead of Address made it work.